# Story identification: SF with spaceships in the form of tarot symbols

Tags: story-identification

This was a SF book where there were 4 factions, each with spaceships in the form of the tarot symbols (swords, cups, wands, pentacles). I believe it was a novel not a short story, but I can't be sure - I read it more than 30 years ago! Thanks.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/looking-for-the-name-and-author-of-short-story-about-sea-creatures-that-need-a-t (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: So, did you ever get a chance to read ShadeOfGrey's answer to check, Toby?

Comment: Gosh, I moved from UK to NL just after this and totally forgot about it. I've found book 1 on sale in NL, so I've ordered it (I miss English libraries!).

Answer (score 6):

Possible match is the "[Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(novels))" series by [Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Anthony). It was written more than 30 years ago.

And from the Wikipedia article:

> The themes of Tarot and of various myths of Sphere Sol (in this case that of Perseus and Andromeda) are carried throughout this novel as well -- for example, the interSphere fleet of starships has forms analogous to the Tarot suits of Disks, Cups, Wands and Swords.

Comment: That sounds pretty likely, thank you, though I don't remember the Kirlian transfers or Spheres. I'll let you know once I've read it :)